# Error in setalloccol(x) : verbose must be TRUE or FALSE --- unknown the error source

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am running into a really weird problem in Rstudio that I have no clue how to fix it, since I don't know which function/packages caused it. I ran the entire code last night and it worked perfectly, but now I kept bumping into the error `Error in setalloccol(x) : verbose must be TRUE or FALSE.` My guess is this arises from either the `dplyr` or `data.table` package, but I have no clue on how to fix this error. Could someone offer insights into this issue?

Comment: `setalloccol()` is a function in `data.table`. Could you not isolate the lines causing the error?

Comment: no I couldn't because R does not prompt the line number and there were too many of `data.table.` I might have to guess and inspect it one by one then.

Comment: have you inspected the output of `traceback()` after triggering the error?

Comment: I have not. I just know that function by now ;) Many thanks!!